# Optimization problem for feeding the hungry

Tags: algorithms, optimization, np-complete, sorting

So I am trying to solve a problem. I believe it is $NP$.

Assume we have $F$ cans of food of varying sizes. There are $P$ homeless people at the local shelter, where $F>P$. Each can of food, $i$ , can satisfy $S_i$ level of hunger. Each homeless person, $j$ requires $H_j$ hunger relief. The people and cans are *not* in any sorted order.

I would like to solve this problem in $O( P( \log(P) ) + F )$

The only thing that is coming to mind would be to sort all of the homeless people by level of hunger, ascending, and then satisfy each person with the cans of food until they reach their required level. I am not sure if there is a better solution, or how to describe the approximation ratio of this algorithm. The goal is to satisfy as many people's hunger as possible. We can not share cans, so there is possibly waste. Can anyone lend a hand/brain?

Comment: If people are allowed to share a can, then I think this is a perfect example of a minimum cost flow problem. You set each can as a supplier, each homeless person as a consumer, connect each supplier to all consumers and give all edges equal costs and infinite capacities.

Comment: I think your goal is missing. Is it to feed the maximum number of person? To minimize the waste? Something else?

Comment: People can not share cans. The goal is to satisfy as many people's hunger as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This actually sounds like something for which you would use the Hungarian Algorithm. You could use it to allocate cans to people. Note that the Hungarian Algorithm will allocate one can per person. After finding an initial optimal matching, you could remove satisfied people and used cans and re-run the algorithm. Below is a link with an explanation of the algorithm. Best of luck!

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/305150-data-structures-graph-theory-hungarian-algorithm/